# Source to global env

Tags: linux, bash

I have some script, that I need to source. I want to source it from another script to global environment. Abstract example:

Script 1:

```
#/script1
PATH="$PATH:/something"
```

Script 2:

```
#/script2
source /script1
```

Than I run `bash /script2` and I'm expecting to see updated `PATH` in global env. But it doesn't

More real example:

```
#/somedir/script1
A=$(./someanotherscript)

#/script2
cd /somedir
source script1
```

So, how can I do this thing?

Answer (score 1):

After running `bash script2`, you won't see the change to `PATH` that `script1` made. That change was local to the environment of the process running `script2`. If you want to change `PATH` in the *current* environment, from which you run `script2`, you need to source it as well.

```
$ source script2
$ echo $PATH
```

Comment: Yep, I know it. The question is how to *source* to global env from some script! I just want to put **script1** to `/usr/local/bin` run `script1` to source all needed variables, cause I can't just run neither `source script2`(It uses another path), nor `source script1`(problem in bash-completion =) )

Comment: @smt - It's unclear what you mean by _It uses another path_ and _problem in bash-completion =)_.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are not exporting the variable, see the following:

```
# script1.sh
PATH="/new:$PATH"
env
```

In this case, `env`, even in this script won't have access to the new path, because you need to do this:

```
# script1.sh
export PATH="/new:$PATH"
env
```

Comment: `PATH` should already be exported, as any process executing a script should have inherited `PATH` from *its* parent.